# Can I load an external SVG file once, then clone copies multiple time?

Tags: javascript, svg, dom

I have an application that I have created a template SVG file for, but depending on user interaction, will need to create multiple (say 6 to 20) instances of the image and modify each independently through code. I know how to load the file into an object element, and how to access and modify the elements within the image, but I'm trying to find if it is possible to do this without having to import the SVG source file for each object as it's created, or can I somehow buffer the source file as an XML structure and then copy that? My target environment is plain HTML and javascript.

For reference, I need to make a navigable display of the nodes and edges of a graph describing the Tower of London cognitive assessment. I want to place an image of the balls and posts arrangement in a circle for each of the nodes and allow the user to traverse the graph. The SVG source file has the balls and posts, to represent a particular node I just change the position of the circle elements that represent the balls to move them to the appropriate post. I could brute force this by loading a new copy of the SVG template for each object representing a node but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: If it is an external SVG file, and you are not changing the URI, then it is cached by the Browser. For dynamically creating SVG [take inspiration from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71917814/center-text-element-over-an-svg/71921950#71921950) Or clone the Elements yourself with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: You can [clone any element you wish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) together with all children.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - this is what I'm doing, same SVG source file needing to be loaded as many times are required. I will be adding and deleting the graph nodes dynamically as the user interacts with the display.

Comment: @RobertLongson - do you have a sense as to the execution speed of the two approaches? Assuming the information about the browser caching the SVG file is correct, I wouldn't expect much difference. Either way I'll still have to create variables to access the internals of the SVG so I can manipulate them.

Comment: Try it and see as always on all the O/S, browsers, graphics cards, browser versions you care about. And bear in mind they all change.

Comment: @RobertLongson 1: adding the objects as required by using <object data="source.svg> to load the same source file (cached by browser)  -or- 2: create clones of the first one through var orgNode = document.querySelector("#orgid") and then var newNode = orgNode.cloneNode(true) as required

Comment: Looks like you might want to edit that into your question

Comment: @RobertLongson - I will perform the test and report the results. I'll try Chrome, Edge,  Firefox and Safari, and do this on my desktop and laptop to see what differences the hardware makes.